# Multiple Sorting on LINQ (nested) method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, sorting

I have the below LINQ method which gets called from a `User Control` and dumped straight to a standard `DataGridView`.  My users want it default sorted, first, by `DisenrollmentDate` and then, `Member Name`.  Right now, with the code below, it sorts by `DisenrollmentDate` ONLY.

---

`BLLCmo.cs`

```
    public static DataTable GetAllMembers(Guid workerID)
    {
        var AllEnrollees = from enrollment in context.tblCMOEnrollments
                               where enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID == workerID || enrollment.CMONurseID == workerID
                               join supportWorker in context.tblSupportWorkers on enrollment.EconomicSupportWorkerID equals supportWorker.SupportWorkerID into workerGroup
                               from worker in workerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               orderby enrollment.DisenrollmentDate ascending 
                               select new
                                       {
                                           enrollment.ClientID,
                                           MemberName = BLLConnect.MemberName(enrollment.ClientID),
                                           NurseName = BLLAspnetdb.NurseName(enrollment.CMONurseID),
                                           SocialWorkerName =BLLAspnetdb.SocialWorkerName(enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID),
                                           enrollment.DisenrollmentDate,
                                           enrollment.EnrollmentDate,
                                           ESFirstName = worker.FirstName,
                                           ESLastName = worker.LastName,
                                           ESPhone = worker.Phone
                                       };

        var dataTable = AllEnrollees.CopyLinqToDataTable();

        return dataTable;
    }
```

---

`BLLConnect.cs`

```
    public static String MemberName(Int32 personID)
    {
        var memberName = from person in context.tblPersons
                         where person.PersonID == personID
                         orderby person.LastName ascending 
                         select person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName;

        return memberName.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add more ordering clauses in your `orderby` statement, separated by a comma.

```
    public static DataTable GetAllMembers(Guid workerID)
    {
        var AllEnrollees = from enrollment in context.tblCMOEnrollments
                               where enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID == workerID || enrollment.CMONurseID == workerID
                               join supportWorker in context.tblSupportWorkers on enrollment.EconomicSupportWorkerID equals supportWorker.SupportWorkerID into workerGroup
                               from worker in workerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               let memberName = BLLConnect.MemberName(enrollment.ClientID)
                               orderby enrollment.DisenrollmentDate ascending, memberName ascending
                               select new
                                       {
                                           enrollment.ClientID,
                                           MemberName = memberName,
                                           NurseName = BLLAspnetdb.NurseName(enrollment.CMONurseID),
                                           SocialWorkerName =BLLAspnetdb.SocialWorkerName(enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID),
                                           enrollment.DisenrollmentDate,
                                           enrollment.EnrollmentDate,
                                           ESFirstName = worker.FirstName,
                                           ESLastName = worker.LastName,
                                           ESPhone = worker.Phone
                                       };

        var dataTable = AllEnrollees.CopyLinqToDataTable();

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Note that I used the `let` keyword to extract the `memberName` once and then use it both for ordering and the return value.

Comment: This seems like it will work.  Thanks!!! Unfortunately it is throwing an exception on the `CopyLinqToDataTable` part for me...I should just quite using `DataTables` :\

Comment: No matter what I do, when I go to assign the results to the DataGridView's DataSource it throws this exception--> `Method 'System.String MemberName(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

Comment: Yes, but that's a different issue. Basically, it tells you that it can't translate the Expression Tree that contains a method call into T-SQL. Try to inline that expression into the query.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured it was seperate.  Thanks for the solution to the first problem.  Now off to research in lining expressions in to queries