# Nested LINQ Method throwing a `Not Supported...` Exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, exception, let

This is a follow up from here -->[multiple-sorting-on-linq-nested-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533831/multiple-sorting-on-linq-nested-method) .

Basically, on `let memberName = ...` it is throwing this exception `Method 'System.String MemberName(Int32)' has no supported translation to SQL.` and I am not figuring out the solution.

Also, `BLLCmo` and `BLLConnect` actually use **TWO** different *DataBases*.  The original app(not mine) uses 4 Seperate DB's so I am trying to make due.

---

`BLLCmo.cs`

```
    public static DataTable GetAllMembers(Guid workerID)
    {
        var AllEnrollees = from enrollment in context.tblCMOEnrollments
                               where enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID == workerID || enrollment.CMONurseID == workerID
                               join supportWorker in context.tblSupportWorkers on enrollment.EconomicSupportWorkerID equals supportWorker.SupportWorkerID into workerGroup
                               from worker in workerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                               let memberName = BLLConnect.MemberName(enrollment.ClientID)
                               orderby enrollment.DisenrollmentDate ascending, memberName ascending 
                               select new
                                       {
                                           enrollment.ClientID,
                                           MemberName = memberName,
                                           NurseName = BLLAspnetdb.NurseName(enrollment.CMONurseID),
                                           SocialWorkerName =BLLAspnetdb.SocialWorkerName(enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID),
                                           enrollment.DisenrollmentDate,
                                           enrollment.EnrollmentDate,
                                           ESFirstName = worker.FirstName,
                                           ESLastName = worker.LastName,
                                           ESPhone = worker.Phone
                                       };

        var dataTable = AllEnrollees.CopyLinqToDataTable();

        return dataTable;
    }
```

---

`BLLConnect.cs`

```
    public static String MemberName(Int32 personID)
    {
        var memberName = from person in context.tblPersons
                         where person.PersonID == personID
                         select person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName;

        return memberName.SingleOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with indicating what you have tried that doesn't work. It could save us all some time, and/or we might know the missing magic words that make a "nearly working" version into "working".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that LINQ to SQL is trying to translate your method into SQL. Since `MemberName` isn't valid SQL, it gives up. Instead, you'll need to pull down the data you need from SQL and then call your methods (and sort) in a separate LINQ to Objects query:

```
public static DataTable GetAllMembers(Guid workerID)
{
    var AllEnrollees =
        from enrollment in context.tblCMOEnrollments
        where enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID == workerID || enrollment.CMONurseID == workerID
        join supportWorker in context.tblSupportWorkers on enrollment.EconomicSupportWorkerID equals supportWorker.SupportWorkerID into workerGroup
        from worker in workerGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            enrollment.ClientID,
            enrollment.CMONurseID,
            enrollment.CMOSocialWorkerID,
            enrollment.DisenrollmentDate,
            enrollment.EnrollmentDate,
            ESFirstName = worker.FirstName,
            ESLastName = worker.LastName,
            ESPhone = worker.Phone
        };

    var result =
        from enrollee in AllEnrollees.AsEnumerable()
        let memberName = BLLConnect.MemberName(enrollee.ClientID)
        orderby enrollee.DisenrollmentDate ascending, memberName ascending 
        select new
        {
            enrollee.ClientID,
            MemberName = memberName,
            NurseName = BLLAspnetdb.NurseName(enrollee.CMONurseID),
            SocialWorkerName = BLLAspnetdb.SocialWorkerName(enrollee.CMOSocialWorkerID),
            enrollee.DisenrollmentDate,
            enrollee.EnrollmentDate,
            enrollee.ESFirstName,
            enrollee.ESLastName,
            enrollee.ESPhone
        };

    return result.CopyLinqToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: This is one of those solutions that are so simple and so nice that I feel stupid for not getting there on my own.  It works great!